# Erro ao instalar pacote ou atualizar Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, gem

Olá! 
Quando aplico qualquer comando `gem install qualqueroutragem` ou `gem update --system` ocorre este tipo de erro:

> "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
>       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) "

[image: error argument]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Reinstale o Ruby

Comment: siga esse tutorial oficial -> https://guides.railsgirls.com/install#setup-for-linux

Comment: não adiantou nenhuma das opções...

Comment: Versão do Ruby e do SO que está utilizando? Obs.: Rodei o mesmo comando num Lubuntu 16.04 e Ruby 2.5.1p57 e foi sem problemas

Comment: Qual sistema operacional? 
Qual gerenciador ruby está utilizando/ como foi instalado e qual versão do ruby?